# Is there a Keras function to obtain the compile options?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Knowing that i can get layers information from an already built model with:

```
model.layers[index].get_config()
```

Is there a way to get the ***compile*** information of a model? Such as loss function used, optimizer, metrics etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [source code that saves a model - `_serialize_model()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ecac367b2372b5f2326fcd3ddd11718323427f4e/keras/engine/saving.py), there is:

```
h5dict['training_config'] = json.dumps({
                'optimizer_config': {
                    'class_name': model.optimizer.__class__.__name__,
                    'config': model.optimizer.get_config()
                },
                'loss': model.loss,
                'metrics': model._compile_metrics,
                'weighted_metrics': model._compile_weighted_metrics,
                'sample_weight_mode': model.sample_weight_mode,
                'loss_weights': model.loss_weights,
            }, default=get_json_type).encode('utf8')
```

You can then use:

```
loss = model.loss
optimizer_class_name = model.optimizer.__class__.__name__
optimizer_config = model.optimizer.get_config()
metrics = model._compile_metrics
weighted_metrics = model._compile_weighted_metrics
sample_weight_mode = model.sample_weight_mode
loss_weights = model.loss_weights
```

Comment: Love you. Kudos!